# webpack and oclazyload - specify full url for require()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, require, webpack, oclazyload

My application's javascript sits on a different domain to the index.html

This causes me a problem when using the awesome ocLazyLoad. The request for the lazy loaded module is made from the domain the index.html lives in.

eg:-

index.html = https://domain.com/index.html

app.bundle.js = https://different-domain.com/js/app.bundle.js

Request for lazy loaded bundle becomes = https://domain.com/1.1.bundle.js

When it should be: https://different-domain.com/js/1.1.bundle.js

route resolve:

```
resolve: {
    load: function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
        let deferred = $q.defer();
        require.ensure([], function () {
            let module = require('./path/to/module.js');
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: 'moduleName'               
            });
            deferred.resolve(module);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could ensure the get request is made to the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on the webpack gitter and someone kindly pointed me in the direction of `output.publicPath` which solves the problem.